# A question about graphs and connected components

Tags: graph-theory

Let $X$ be a finite connected graph (no multi-edges , no loops). Let $X$ satisfies following property:

> *after removing any vertex (with edges from it), the graph becomes disconnected (i.e. ignorence of any vertex and edges from it gives more than one graphs).*

Is it possible to describe structures of such graphs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There **are no such graphs.**

If such a graph existed, consider the minimal $n$ such that a graph with $n$ edges that has your property exists, and let $G$ be such a graph.

The graph can have no vertices of degree $0$ or $1$ -- for such a vertex can be removed without increasing the number of connected components.

But any finite graph with vertex degrees $\ge 2$ has a cycle. Choose one of the edges $e$ in the cycle, and remove that. Then $G\setminus\{e\}$ is still connected, and no matter which vertex $v$ we remove from it, we have
$$ G\setminus\{e,v\} \subseteq G\setminus\{v\} $$
Since by assumption $G\setminus\{v\}$ is not connected and $G\setminus\{e,v\}$ has the same vertices, it cannot be connected either.

So $G\setminus\{e\}$ *also* has your property, which contradicts the assumption that $G$ had a minimal number of edges with that property.

Comment: Upvoted; although "any finite graph with [all] vertex degrees $\geq 2$ has a cycle" is intuitively obvious, but... simple proof?

Comment: @ChasBrown: Start somewhere and keep going down a random edge that you have not used yet, until you reach a vertex you have been at before. You can't reach a dead end because there's always an edge other than the one you arrived by, and once you meet your own trail, the path you have taken since you were there first will be a cycle.

Comment: @Hennig - ah, right, 'until you reach a vertex you have been at before'; because there are only a finite number of vertices.

Comment: @ChasBrown: Correct.

Comment: More simply, take two vertices at maximum distance from each other and delete one of them.

Comment: Nitpick: the graph $K_1$ may or may not be a counterexample, depending on just how you define "graph" and "connected".